# Incorrect lookat matrix

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

I've started working on shadow maps for directional lights and for that I need a lookAt matrix, but when I tried constructing from example of an online tutorial it looked something like this:

[image]

It currently looks like this:
https://media.giphy.com/media/QrMnqBBJZuATu/giphy.gif

I've tried multiple ways of constructing it but with no success, I checked if the normalization, cross and translation functions weren't correct but that wasn't the case. I've also tried changing from column-major matrices to row-major matrices but with no luck. Would someone be able to point out what I did wrong?

Lookat matrix constructing:

Center vector = (0, 0, 0),
Up vector = (0, 1, 0)

```
Matrix4f Matrix4f::lookAt(const Vector3f& position, const Vector3f& center, const Vector3f& up) {
        Matrix4f out(1.0f); 

        Vector3f z = position.substract(center).normalize(); 


        Vector3f y = up;

        Vector3f x = y.cross(z).normalize();

        y = z.cross(x);

        out.mElements[0 * 4 + 0] = x.x;
        out.mElements[0 * 4 + 1] = x.y;
        out.mElements[0 * 4 + 2] = x.z;

        out.mElements[1 * 4 + 0] = y.x;
        out.mElements[1 * 4 + 1] = y.y;
        out.mElements[1 * 4 + 2] = y.z;

        out.mElements[2 * 4 + 0] = z.x;
        out.mElements[2 * 4 + 1] = z.y;
        out.mElements[2 * 4 + 2] = z.z;

        return (out * Matrix4f::translation(Vector3f(-position.x, -position.y, -position.z)));
    }
}
```

Credit for code: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5577765/rabbid76

This is how I pass a matrix to the shader:

```
void Shader::setMat4(const char* name, const math::Matrix4f& matrix){
    glUniformMatrix4fv(getUniformLocation(name), 1, GL_TRUE, matrix.mElements);
}
```

After I've calculated the lookAt matrix I directly pass it to the vertex shader to the uniform: `view` and calculate a point like this:

```
gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);
```

And this is how my matrix multiplication works:

```
Matrix4f Matrix4f::multiply(const Matrix4f& other) const {
    Matrix4f out;
    for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
            fl32 o = 0;
            for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
                o += this->mElements[c + y * 4] * other.mElements[x + c * 4];                   }
            out.mElements[x + y * 4] = o;
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Edit: updated picture
Edit: Added a more detailed description

Comment: Doesn't GLSL provide a `lookAt` function?  Is there a reason you are doing this by hand instead of letting the shader handle the calculation?

Comment: @0x5453 To save the shader from calculating so much and trying to figure out how the lookat matrix works.

Comment: @0x5453: "*Doesn't GLSL provide a lookAt function?*" No, it does not.

Comment: @0x5453 glsl certainly doesnt, but there are opengl centric libraries that do, [glm](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.2/api/a00245.html) being one of them, and since its on github i suggest OP take a look at [its implementation](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/glm/gtc/matrix_transform.inl#L511)

Comment: @Borgleader Ahh yes, glm is what I was thinking of.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Your link is a link to this exact question.  Did you mis-paste?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I thought the up direction was positive y to move up wasn't it? And my projection matrix couldn't be the problem since it works fine with a view matrix with only a translation.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Indeed.

Comment: How do you pass a Matrix4f to OpenGL? What is the conception behind matrix multiplication? I mean, is a point transformed by `M*p` or `p*M`? How do you use the result of `lookAt`? I mean, is it the matrix of the camera, or is it the inverse of it? We need to know these things to answer this question.

Comment: One piece still missing: the `operator*`, which is used to multiply two matrices together. But, if it has a sane implementation, that I don't know what could be the problem here. You have a row-major `Matrix4f`. `lookAt` returns the inverse camera matrix. It is all fine.

Comment: However, looking at the animation... is the camera field of view animated? It looks like as if it were changing

Comment: @geza No it's not animated I was moving around to see how it deformed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of trying to make the lookat matrix working I had given up on way of constructing the lookat matrix, instead I constructed a lookat matrix based on the position of the camera and position the camera should look at, using trigonometry functions I was able to create the result which I was seeking.

My current way of constructing a lookat matrix:

```
Matrix4f Matrix4f::lookAt(const Vector3f& position, const Vector3f& center) {
        Vector3f deltaVector = (position - center).normalize();

        fl32 yaw = (fl32)radToDeg(atan(deltaVector.x / deltaVector.z));
        fl32 pitch = (fl32)radToDeg(acos(Vector2f(deltaVector.x, deltaVector.z).magnitude()));

        if (deltaVector.z > 0)
            yaw = yaw - 180.0f;

        Matrix4f yRotation = Matrix4f::rotation(Vector3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), -yaw);
        Matrix4f xRotation = Matrix4f::rotation(Vector3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), pitch);

        Matrix4f translation = Matrix4f::translation(position);

        return (translation * (yRotation * xRotation));
    }
```

Comment: No needed trigonometry. And you may incur in sign issues. Your first approach was good, with the normalize-fix. Just that you defined a row-order matrix, instead of a col-order one, which is what OpenGL uses. Anyhow, your picture seems good, except for perhaps a triangle, closer to the camera, hidding the rest. Also, yes, `position` is where the camera is and `center` is where the camera looks at, both in world-coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

You need to normalize s before u is calculated. I'm not sure if it is the only problem

Comment: Good catch!. But indeed isn't the only problem.

Comment: Can you please update the picture. What's wrong with it currently?

Answer (score 3):

If your positions (`position`, `center`) and the `up` vector are in viewport space, then the Z-Axis of the view matrix is the inverse line of sight and the Y-Axis is the up vector. See the following code:

[image]

```
Matrix4f Matrix4f::lookAt(const Vector3f& position, const Vector3f& center, const Vector3f& up)
{
    Matrix4f out(1.0f); // I suppose this initilizes a 4*4 identity matrix

    // Z-Axis is the line of sight
    Vector3f z = position.substract(center).normalize(); // inverse line of sight

    // Y-Axis is the up vector
    Vector3f y = up;

    // X-Axis is the cross product of Y-Axis and Z-Axis
    Vector3f x = y.cross(z).normalize();

    // orthonormalize the Y-Axis
    y = z.cross( x );

    out.mElements[0*4 + 0] = x.x;
    out.mElements[0*4 + 1] = x.y;
    out.mElements[0*4 + 2] = x.z;

    out.mElements[1*4 + 0] = y.x;
    out.mElements[1*4 + 1] = y.y;
    out.mElements[1*4 + 2] = y.z;

    out.mElements[2*4 + 0] = z.x;
    out.mElements[2*4 + 1] = z.y;
    out.mElements[2*4 + 2] = z.z;

    return (out * Matrix4f::translation(Vector3f(-position.x, -position.y, -position.z)));
}
```

Comment: What are the variables p and t?

Comment: It's seems to be working better
https://media.giphy.com/media/QrMnqBBJZuATu/giphy.gif

Comment: It's not quite what I expected. What I want is to be able to make the lookAt matrix work(Or perhaps the functions around it that might not work) so I'm able to construct environment for rendering a shadow map.